# How to remove the history or alter it in React-Router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to make the user delete the n-number of history when moving back from a page. I have tried to

```
componentWillUnmount = () => {
    const histLen = this.props.history.length
    // Using 2 to route back to Investments Landing page
     this.props.history.go(2 - histLen)
  }

  backToRandomPage = () => {
    this.props.history.goBack()
  }
```

But it doesn't delete the history and lets the user move forward to those pages which were skipped

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the `pop` method to achieve this. DO something like this

```js
componentWillUnmount = () => {
    const histLen = this.props.history.length

    // Looping over how many routes you want to go back.
    // POP action will remove that entry
    for (let i = 1; i <= histLen; i += 1) {
      this.props.history.pop();
    } 
}

backToRandomPage = () => {
    this.props.history.goBack()
}
```

Comment: Getting **TypeError: _this.props.history.pop is not a function**

Comment: There were some underlying assumptions I made before posting the answer. Do you mind pasting the entire code for your component?

Comment: The component is wrapped as **export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RandomComponent))** and imports are `import connect from 'react-redux/es/connect/connect'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'`